# Limit the number of ssh connections ansible tower will spin up

Tags: ansible, ansible-awx, ansible-tower

Is there a way to limit the number of ssh connections ansible tower will spin up when running a large job targeting large number of hosts?

We have pipelining enabled but the job seem to be spinning off large number of ssh connections preemptively.

Answer (score 1):

Go to **Settings > Jobs** and set limit in **Maximum number of forks per job**

https://www.ansible.com/blog/ansible-performance-tuning (see the section on "Know Your Forks")